# Apache Spark: sort results before or after collect for a small collection?

Tags: apache-spark

The title pretty much says it all.

As an example, in [this course](http://fruzenshtein.com/coursera-spark-week-1/), they define those two methods:

```
def rankLangsUsingIndex(index: RDD[(String, Iterable[WikipediaArticle])]): List[(String, Int)] = {
  index.map(...)
    .sortBy(pair => pair._2) // <- sortBy BEFORE collect
    .collect()
    .toList
    .reverse
}

def rankLangsReduceByKey(langs: List[String], rdd: RDD[WikipediaArticle]): List[(String, Int)] = {
    rdd.flatMap(...)
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)
      .collect()
      .toList
      .sortWith(_._2 > _._2) // <- sort AFTER collect
  }
```

The expected output is very small.

I wonder if there **a reason why the sort is done before/after collect** ? In general, is there a rule to help us choose the best one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you want to achieve.
I would argue, that it rarely makes sense to sort collected output in code, but that it also *shouldn't make a difference*.

If your data is big enough, that it would make a difference - then you shouldn't be collecting in the first place.
If your data is small enough, then you probably want to be able to sort dynamically/interactively - and it makes little sense to sort in a hardocded manner - rather you want to sort inside the front-end.

Unless for some reason, you're collecting hundreds of thousands of entries to the driver, there's no point of sorting in a distributed manner.

Actually, here's my suggestion: use whichever API you consider to be easier to maintain. In the example case, the use of reverse makes the code slightly encumbered, and so I'd probably prefer the second one.

A reason to favor sorting in a distributed manner, is if there's something to be gained by sorting in the rest of the query - by sorting locally you write around the Spark query optimizer - potentially doing work twice.